# Change data using API key

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a sheet on Google spreadsheets.

I've enabled Google Spreadsheets API in developres' console and got API key.

Can I use this API key for manipulating my own sheet (which is created on the same account I enabled API) or I need to enable OAuth as well as for accessing any private data?

Comment: All writes require OAuth with the Sheets REST API. You can use the Apps Script Spreadsheet service in some cases, such as configuring a webapp to execute as you and sending requests to it.

Comment: You always need OAuth, both for reading and writing. Do you use a specific language?

Answer (score 2):

API keys are used to access public data.  Private user data needs the permission of the owner to access.  It is accessed using an access token to get an access token you need to either use oauth2 or a service account.

Note: You could set the sheet to public then you will be able to read the sheet with the api key but this will be read only access you will not be able to edit the sheet with an api key.